# $\infty$ tosses with a symmetrical coin. With prob. $= 1$ there are $\infty$ many events "in the first $n$ tosses there were as many eagles as tails"

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, random-walk

We toss an infinite number of times with a symmetrical coin. $A_{2n}$ denotes the event that in the first $2n$ tosses there were as many eagles as tails. Show that there are infinitely many $A_{2n}$ events with probability 1.

Solution:

$S_{2n}$ is a sum of "additional" eagles in  $2n$ (if in $2n = 10$ tosses there are $6$ eagles and $4$ tails then $S_{2n} = 2$).

$J_{2n}$ is an indicator variable for the event that the number of eagles is equal to number of tails (so in some sense it returns to origin / balance = its starting point). The total number of visits to the origin is given by:
$$V = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} J_{2n}$$
By the linearity of the expected value:
$$\mathbb{E}[V] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}[J_{2n}] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P} [ S_{2n} = S_0 ]$$

From Bergnoulli:
$$\mathbb{P} [ S_{2n} = S_0 ] = {{2n}\choose{n}} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^{n} \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^n = {{2n}\choose{n}} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$$

From Stirling's formula:
$$\mathbb{P} [ S_{2n} = S_0 ] = {{2n}\choose{n}} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} = \frac{2n!}{n! \cdot n!} \frac{1}{2^{2n}} \approx \frac{\sqrt{4 \pi n} \cdot e^{-2n} (2n)^{2n}}{(\sqrt{2 \pi n} \cdot e^{-n} n^n)^2 2^{2n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}}$$

We know that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} n^{-a}$ converges only if $a > 1$. Therefore we have:

$$\mathbb{E}[V] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{P} [ S_{2n} = S_0 ] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi n}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} = \infty$$

Let $q$ be the probability that $S_{2n}$ returns to its starting point $S_{0}$. Assuming that number of returns is finite, its distribution is given by:
$$\mathbb{P}[V = k | \text{ where } k \neq \infty] = q^{k-1}(1-q) \ \ \ \text{for: } k = 1, 2, 3...$$

Then we have that:
$$\mathbb{E}[V] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} k \mathbb{P}[V = k] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} k q^{k-1}(1-q) = \frac{1-q}{q} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} k q^{k} = \frac{1-q}{q} \cdot \frac{q}{(1-q)^2}= \frac{1}{1-q} < \infty$$

But we know that $\mathbb{E}[V] = \infty$, so by contradiction $q = 1$ and therefore we have that:
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{ number of returns is finite }] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[V = k | \text{ where } k \neq \infty] = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} q^{k-1}(1-q) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0 = 0$$

Therefore:
$$\mathbb{P}[\text{ (number of returns is finite)' }] = 1 - \mathbb{P}[\text{ number of returns is infinite }] = 1 - 0 = 1$$

Is that correct?

Comment: What if there is non-zero probability for both finite and infinite number of returns?

Comment: There is $0$ probablility for finite number of returns.  @mihaild

Comment: It's true, but I don't think you have proved it. In your calculation of $\mathbb E V$ you didn't include term $V = \infty$.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right. Do you know how could I fix that? @mihaild

Comment: What coinage has eagles on the obverse?

Comment: Some abstract one, doesn't matter that much :D @PaulSinclair

Comment: Obviously not. I was just curious.

Comment: Polish zloty @PaulSinclair

Comment: This is equivalent to the recurrence of the simple symmetric random walk in dimension $1$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer I know, but still, I don't know how to prove it / if it can be proven with tools I have used.